# whois lookups on the IP addresses

Tags: php, whois

> $ host 64.34.119.12
>       12.119.34.64.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer stackoverflow.com.

How is this Carried out in php? I am planning to do lookup for searching Google's ip. How do i do implement this?

Like in above example it is stalkoverflow.com

I want to determine their netblock and do strstr on their netblock for "google"

if it is matched, it will , `echo "Yeah , its google"`

Comment: Look at the related section, to the right.

Comment: Note that other people may identify themselves as Google as well (it's just a DNS post after all), and that Google very well may identify themselves as something else from time to time to catch people trying to trick their system.

Comment: Yeah, but most of time. Reverse and forward lookup will reveal that. OR Simple Whois Lookup.

Answer (score 3):

Your looking for `gethostbyaddr(string ip_address)`, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

Example:

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

echo $hostname;
?>
```